# Incorrect outputs for simple solution

Tags: c++, string

Codeforces problem 373A-http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/373/A

Instead of multiple if statements for counting number of elements of each number,I have tried to check for given condition after sorting the array.I am getting incorrect output for 1st test case(given in the link for the problem).What is wrong with my approach?What should I change in my solution.

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int k,i,j,a;
char panel[17],temp,output[4];

int main()
{
    cin>>k;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    cin>>panel[i];

    for(i=0;i<16;i++) //Bubble sort.
    {
        for(j=0;j<(15-i);j++)
        {
            if(panel[j]>panel[j+1])
            {
                temp=panel[j+1];
                panel[j+1]=panel[j];
                panel[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    a=1;
    strcpy(output,"YES");
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        if(panel[i]==panel[i+1])
        ++a;
        else
        a=1;

        if(a>(2*k));
        {
            strcpy(output,"NO");
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<output;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a semi-colon after the `if` statement:

```
    if(a>(2*k));
```

That means, it's always going copy "NO" and break the loop. Remove it.